# How to reduce the margin at the top

Tags: margins, vertical-spacing

I am trying to reduce the margin on the top of my Latex document but am unable to do so. Here is the code for my Latex document -

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
% if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.94]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% personal data
\name{xxxxx}{}
\phone[mobile]{(+1) xxxxx      
\email{xxxxx}                               
\social[linkedin]{xxxxx} 
\social[github]{xxxxx}




 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}

\vspace{1pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\cventry{2022 - 2024}{Masters in Computer Engineering}{xxxx}{Blacksburg, Virginia, United States of America}{\textit{}}{}}


  \textbf{Courses Taken:} Computer Architecture, Computer Vision, Network Security, Advanced Real Time Systems, Cyber-Physical Systems

\item{\cventry{2013 - 2017}{Bachelor of Engineering in xxxxx}{xxxx Institute of Technology}{xxxx}{\textit{}}{}}


  \textbf{Related Coursework:} Embedded System Design, Programming in C and Data Structures, Microcontrollers, Microprocessors, Operating Systems
 
 \vspace{1pt}



\end{itemize}


\end{document}




%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

I've tried fixing it for a while and have seen other questions related to this but that hasn't helped me much. So any help here would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Change `\usepackage[scale=0.94]{geometry}` to `\usepackage[topmargin=<desired size>, scale=0.94]{geometry}`

Comment: @Zarko - Thank you. But this makes the title ( my name) go to the top of the page. What I want to do is to reduce the gap between the main title and the education section

Comment: Than insert `\vspace{- <length>}` after your name.

Comment: tried that. for some reason, it doesnt work

Comment: My last try:  `\vspace*{- <length>}˙` ...

Comment: Geometry has two different meanings for top depending on includehead.  Compare figures 1 and 2 in the manual.  Of course this assumes moderncv uses normal headers.